# Http Post Form request in Puppeteer chrome headless

Tags: http, http-post, puppeteer

I am doing some web scraping using [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).
1.I need to use the post method to post a form and also specify the request header.

2.Download the response as pdf file.
I am not entirely sure how to write the syntax of Request and Response class of puppeteer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I realize this is 5 years old, but there's no code or site here and therefore no way to help.